# text overwriting over another paragrah when i use line height

Tags: html, css, line-height

my text in the p element is overwriting over next p element when I use line-height to 2px, I am new to coding please help here's the code

```css
.main-section p{
    font-size: 16px;
    word-spacing: 1px;
    line-height: 2px;
    color: #252426;
  }
```

```html
<section class="main-section" id="introduction">
            <h2>Introduction</h2>
            <p>JavaScript is a cross-platform, object-oriented scripting language....JavaScript is a cross-platform, object-oriented scripting language....JavaScript is a cross-platform, object-oriented scripting language....JavaScript is a cross-platform, object-oriented scripting language....word limit</p>
            <p>JavaScript contains a standard library of objects, such as Array...JavaScript contains a standard library of objects, such as Array...JavaScript contains a standard library of objects, such as Array...word limit</p>
```

paragraph overwriting

Comment: 2px? Popular browsers support 12px at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Line Height not Less than font size if less then font size then
> overlap.

```css
.main-section p{
    font-size: 16px;
    word-spacing: 1px;
    line-height: 16px;
    color: #252426;
  }
```

```html
<section class="main-section" id="introduction">
            <h2>Introduction</h2>
            <p>JavaScript is a cross-platform, object-oriented scripting language....JavaScript is a cross-platform, object-oriented scripting language....JavaScript is a cross-platform, object-oriented scripting language....JavaScript is a cross-platform, object-oriented scripting language....word limit</p>
            <p>JavaScript contains a standard library of objects, such as Array...JavaScript contains a standard library of objects, such as Array...JavaScript contains a standard library of objects, such as Array...word limit</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the line-height property to make it auto-measure.

```css
.main-section p{
    font-size: 16px;
    word-spacing: 1px;
    color: #252426;
  }
```

```html
<section class="main-section" id="introduction">
            <h2>Introduction</h2>
            <p>JavaScript is a cross-platform, object-oriented scripting language....JavaScript is a cross-platform, object-oriented scripting language....JavaScript is a cross-platform, object-oriented scripting language....JavaScript is a cross-platform, object-oriented scripting language....word limit</p>
            <p>JavaScript contains a standard library of objects, such as Array...JavaScript contains a standard library of objects, such as Array...JavaScript contains a standard library of objects, such as Array...word limit</p>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

`line-height` property calculates it from the beginning of the first line to the beginning of the next line so when you give it `1px` it will overlap when the space is less than the height of the font's size

you can use a multiplier value like:

```
line-height: 1.2;
```

if you want 1px line height use `calc()` function:

```
line-height: calc(1 + 1px);
```

Comment: The second value is invalid (at least in Chrome).